# Find the magnitude of the $x$ and $y$ components to the nearest whole number?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Find the magnitude of the $x$ and $y$ components of $V$ to the nearest whole number:

1. $||V||=27$ and $V$ has a direction of $60°$
2. $||V||=12$ and $V$ has a direction of $107°$

Please help.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram? If so, apply some trigonometry to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Big hint:** Draw first a unit (radius $1$) circle, then a circle with radius $\|V\|$, both centered at $(0,0)$. Then the points on the unit circle are given by $(x_1,y_1)=(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ for angles given by $\alpha$.

The question is now, what are the coordinates of points on the circle with radius $\|V\|$ (for certain we know that the point must lie on that circle). If we scale the point $(x_1,y_1)$ by a certain factor $C$ (i.e. $(C\cos\alpha,C\sin\alpha)$) we get a new circle with another radius. Which $C$ should we multiply by?